# nodejs process doesn't stop on 'systemctl stop' while running as an Ubuntu systemd service

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, node.js

when trying to stop a nodejs process running from a service file the service is never actually stopped, and just keeps running, forcing me to manually kill the process in htop each time. any ideas on how to make the process actually stop ?

additionally i apologize if this isn't the right place to ask this :(

using this as a service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Next.JS enviro
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=group
Type=simple
KillMode=process
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/website.com
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "npx next start -p 5050"
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Did you get any error when you `stop` the service? You can check more logs about your service by using: `sudo journalctl -xeu yourfile.service` (or `sudo journalctl -xu yourfile.service` to see logs from the beginning)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon noo, no errors, however it does say stuff about the stop job has finished, and the service entering into a dead state, however the node process is still live :[

Comment: Try changing `KillMode=process` to `KillMode=control-group` (from`man systemd.kill` both `KillMode=process` and `KillMode=none` are not recommended)